# Strapi deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strapi

I am new to Strapi and I found it really good, I got my website in development mode locally working perfectly fine but I can not get my head around or find any good guide how to host Strapi on Debian Linux server, that I have, to be part of website and to access Strapi control panel for example `mywebiste.com/admin` so I can add content as blog posts directly by logging in to website admin part. Is that possible or I must use some services like Heroku. if someone can provide in short step by step what to do I will really appreciate that. I tried already create new Strapi project inside `public_html` folder but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use strapi on my project . I hosted strapi on pm2 package. Its very easy.
this documention https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/guides/process-manager.html#install-pm2

don't forget add startup Ubuntu to pm2. Otherwise when Ubuntu started then not starting pm2

I suggest use Ubuntu.

Nginx Configuration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy it to a Linux server, you need to install nginx, and set it up. You can find instructions in official documentation: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/optional-software/nginx-proxy.html#nginx-virtual-host